# How to rename multiple files with a prefix and suffix using a find command

Tags: find, rename

I have the following command which renames a number of files found by the find command by adding the suffix "*processed".  How would I modify this to also add a prefix like "ren*" ?

```
find . -type f -name 'file*.dat' -execdir mv {} {}_processed ';'
```

Comment: `find . -type f -name 'file*.dat' -execdir mv "{}" "ren_{}" \;`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti this won't work because find results has full path format.

Comment: @Ketan, well, depends. GNU find adds `./` to the front even with `-execdir`, the (probably ancient) BSD find on macOS doesn't.

Comment: Oh, of course.  use `"ren_$(basename {})"` perhaps?

Comment: at least with GNU `find` you could do `-execdir sh -c 'for f; do mv -- "$f" "ren_${f##*/}"; done' sh {} +`

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `rename` command (based on Perl expression):

```
find . -type f -name "file*.dat" -execdir rename 's/(file.*?\.dat)$/ren_$1_processed/' {} +
```

Note the rename regex needs to be lazy lest it catches a file in the directory portion. Plus, rename can happily take multiple arguments.

This will rename all files provided by `find` command adding prefix `ren_` and suffix `_processed` on both sides of the *"base"* file name

Comment: Also note that as written, it wouldn't rename a `$'file\n.dat'` file (you'd need to add the `s` flag for `.` to match the newline)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, your approach `rename '$_ = "ren_${_}_processed"'` will not work because of "full path format". You'll get something like `Can't rename ./file2.dat ren_./file2.dat_processed: No such file or directory`. You should have known that having over 210K reputation

Comment: Right, it's true that some `find` implementations include the `./` prefix with `-execdir` while some others don't ([I knew it indeed](/a/256758) but overlooked it here, sorry)